# Firebase -how to paginate based on keys but skip over specific attributes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a video based app. Someone suggested that I use a video recommendation system similar to any other video app that shows videos based on what a user watches. If a user scrolls through 50 videos, and 20 of them are pet related (dogs, cats etc), then as the user scrolls further they would see more animal related videos rather than non animal related videos.

When I pull posts, I paginate based on the snapshot key from newest to oldest. Each video has an attribute like `-category: "pets"` but that has nothing to do with the snapshot key for paging. After determining that user prefers pet video what I was thinking was as the user pages, if the post doesn't contain that attribute, skip it, but there is an issue.

The problem with using an attribute is if the first 50 videos it is determined that the user prefers pet related videos, as they scroll the next 200 videos might not have a pet attribute, which means either skip all 200 videos, or show them all. But if they have to scroll through all 200 then there isn't any point to the recommendation system.

If 10 of the next 50 videos after the 200 do have the pets attribute, using the pagination system below, there is no way to skip all 200 videos and get to the next 10 of the following 50 (basically skipping straight to keys 201 - 250).

**Is there anyway to skip over batches of posts that do not contain a specific attribute?**

```
var snapKey: String?
    
func paginate() {
        
    let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        
    if snapKey == nil {

        postsRef
            .queryOrderedByKey
            .queryLimited(toLast: 20)
            .obsereSingleEvent(of: value, with: (snapshot) {
                    
                guard let firstChild = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
                    
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    // each child is a post, get it, fetch and attach user model, append to datasource, reloadData
                }
                    
                self.snapKey = firstChild.key
            })
            
    } else {
            
        postsRef
            .queryOrderedByKey
            .queryEnding(atValue: snapKey!)
            .queryLimited(toLast: 21)
            .obsereSingleEvent(of: value, with: (snapshot) {
                    
                guard let firstChild = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
                    
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        
                    // each child is a post, get it, fetch and attach user model, append to datasource, reloadData
                }
                    
                self.snapKey = firstChild.key
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to narrow this down to one specific question or issue.  You have at least three different questions here (including the one in the title), one of which is completely off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: which part is off topic so that I can remove it.

Comment: The title - asking if RTDB is suitable.  That's a matter of opinion.  The question asking for something else more suitable is off-topic because it's asking for recommendations for offsite resources.  Focus your question on the functioning of the code at hand.

Comment: I updated the question but kept the context the same

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to skip over batches of posts that do not contain a specific attribute?

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have an NOT EQUAL operation. The closest equivalent is to do two queries: one for the matches before the value, the other for the matches after the value.

So something along the lines of:

```
let query1 = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "category").queryEnding(atValue: "o~")
let query2 = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "category").queryStarting(atValue: "q")
```

Where the `~` is just the last printable ASCII character, so that your first query ends *just before* the first item whose category starts with a `p`.

Comment: Frank thanks for the help but I'm honestly lost, this one went over my head